# Twitter Typeahead data passing

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using twitter typeahead bundle. I have code like this:

```
   var results = new bloodhound({...}) 
   //results is a map in json with the keys ID and displayName. It's  grabbed by ajax call.

    $('#element').typeahead({
    ...
    {
      name: 'Results',
      displayKey: 'displayName',
      source: results.ttAdapter(),
    }...
```

This works very, very well. The results are being populated as users type stuff. However, one issue I have is that when the user clicks "submit", the value I need to grab is not the displayName, but instead the ID.

If the user types, "Exam", let's say the results map looks like: {"id":"100","displayName":"Example1"}. They click on "Example1" and example1 jumps to the text box. However, when the user clicks submit, I want "100" to come from that element, rather than "Example1". Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the typeahead selected handler

```
.on("typeahead:selected", function(event, item) {
    $("#hiddenInputToSubmit").val(item.id);
    return;
}
```

Maybe that could work for you?